# Listview is not populated correctly from database with duplicate rows

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview

I am using `AsyncTask` to populate `Listview` from mysql database through JSON array. The thing is that all my items are being displayed except that the listview in the last rows has duplicate entries.

My [File](http://reservations.cretantaxiservices.gr/files/getbeverages.php) from database as i export them in Ascending order

[Check this explain better what is happening](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aa0srbkaci6yszz/test.avi?dl=0)

And my code:

```
public class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void, List<ProductList>> {
        public JsonReadTask() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), ProgressDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.get_stocks));
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ProductList> doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
                customList = new ArrayList<>();

                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
                //JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("beverages");
                JSONArray array = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("beverages");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonChildNode = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jsonChildNode.getString("name");
                    String price = jsonChildNode.getString("price");
                    String image = jsonChildNode.getString("image");
                    customList.add(new ProductList(image, name, price));

                }
                return customList;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }
            return answer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<ProductList> customList) {
            if(customList == null){
                Log.d("ERORR", "No result to show.");
                return;
            }
            ListDrawer(customList);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }// end async task

    public void accessWebService() {
        JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
        task.execute(new String[]{url});
    }

    public void ListDrawer(List<ProductList> customList) {
        adapter = new ProductListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, customList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

My adapter code even though i think is irrelavant because it works fine on coffees and snacks:

```
public class ProductListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ProductList> {

    public ProductListAdapter(Context context, int layoutId, List<ProductList> items) {
        super(context, layoutId, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View arrayView = convertView;
        ViewHolderItems holder;
        ProductList currentPosition = null;

        if(arrayView == null){
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            arrayView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            currentPosition = getItem(position);
            holder = new ViewHolderItems();
            holder.viewName = (TextView)arrayView.findViewById(R.id.product_name_coffee);
            holder.viewPrice = (TextView)arrayView.findViewById(R.id.product_price_coffee);
            holder.viewImage = (ImageView)arrayView.findViewById(R.id.product_image_coffee);
            arrayView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolderItems) arrayView.getTag();
        }
        if(currentPosition != null){
            holder.viewName.setText(currentPosition.getName());
            holder.viewPrice.setText(currentPosition.getPrice());
            Ion.with(holder.viewImage).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).load(currentPosition.getImage());
        }
        return arrayView;
    }

    static class ViewHolderItems {
        TextView viewName, viewPrice;
        ImageView viewImage;
    }


}
```

My php code:

```
<?php
try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'root', 'password');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM beverages ORDER BY `name` ASC');
$records = array();
$records = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json['beverages'] = $records;
echo json_encode($json);
```

Any idea why this is happening???

Comment: Could you post your `ProductListAdapter`

Comment: I didn't find anything duplicate listed in the video. Am I missing something?

Comment: yes in the bottom it says twice apple crumble and baklava and one more thing even though when i click on the row it gives me the correct names...but the image and name are duplicated....recheck it

Comment: Your json says "sweets" but you are fetching "beverages". Is the link you have posted wrong? Also please post code for `ProductListAdapter` class

Comment: i just updated the code but since i order the items by ascending order it gives me this error....before i did it was fine....

Comment: If the list broke when you introduced ordering, can you post your ordering code? And again - in code you posted  you are working on beverages, not sweets - can you post your sweets-related code?

Comment: the sweets code is the same it just the JSONArray name changes to sweets.

Comment: I don't think ordering really breaks anything. Are you sure that when you just delete ordering from your SQL query then it works correctly?

Comment: no it does not work correctly...and i dont know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in your getView() method, specifically this piece of code:

```
    if(currentPosition != null){
        holder.viewName.setText(currentPosition.getName());
        holder.viewPrice.setText(currentPosition.getPrice());
        Ion.with(holder.viewImage).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).load(currentPosition.getImage());
    }
```

The view's row will only be updated if `currentPosition` is not null --  which only happens if `convertView` is `null`. And if the row's data will not be updated, it will just use what is currently in convertView. That is why some of the data will look duplicated.

To correct this, just you can just remove the wrapping `if` condition and leave the three lines inside it intact.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the adapter in onCreate()

```
List<ProductList> list;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = new ProductListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, list);
}
```

Upate the variable used to invoke array adapter constructor(In this case I have declared another global variable List list and passed this variable in array adapter constructor)

```
public void ListDrawer(List<ProductList> customList) {
    list = customList;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the `getView` method of your list view adapter. I would modify it this way:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolderItems holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolderItems();
        holder.viewName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_name_coffee);
        holder.viewPrice = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_price_coffee);
        holder.viewImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_image_coffee);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolderItems) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.viewName.setText(getItem(position).getName());
    holder.viewPrice.setText(getItem(position).getPrice());
    Ion.with(holder.viewImage).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).load(getItem(position).getImage());


    return convertView;
}
```